# Creating Mean Function for Subset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a function that will take a few parameters and return the total average hourly return.  My data set looks like this:

```
Location    Time    units
1   Columbus    3:35    12
2   Columbus    3:58    199
3   Chicago     6:10    -45
4   Chicago     6:19    87
5   Detroit    12:05    -200
6   Detroit     0:32    11
```

What I would like returned would be

```
Location    Time    units   unitsph
Columbus    7:33        211     27.9
Chicago     12:29       42      3.4
Detroit     12:37      -189    -15.1
```

while also retaining the other items

basically total units produced and units per hour.

I tried out

```
thing <- time %>% group_by(Location) %>% summarize(sum(units))
```

which returned locations and total units but not units per hour. Then I moved to

```
thing <- time %>% group_by(Location) %>% summarize(sum(units)) %>% summarize(sum(Time))
```

which returned

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Time' not found
```

I also tried mutate but to no effect:

```
fin <- mutate(time, as.numeric(sum(Time))/as.numeric(sum(units)))
Error in Summary.factor(c(118L, 131L, 174L, 178L, 57L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any help here much appreciated.  I also have a few other columns that I'd like to retain (they're geocodes for the locations etc), but didn't list those here.  If that's important I can add back in.

Comment: `Play.Time` is not `Time` for starters. Also, how are you summing `12:05` like time objects? How are they stored?

Comment: ah yes, the joys of editing. Play.Time is the actual variable, I made it time in the question for reasons of simplicity. edited to fix that. the time items are stored as factors.  They were generated by lubridate, though honestly I can't remember how I generated them (been improving this one for some time).

Comment: I guess my answer got obsolete know. can you add the output of `dput(time)` to your question to make it more easily reproducible.
Furthermore, the line `thing <- time %>% group_by(Location) %>% summarize(sum(units)) %>% summarize(sum(Time))` contains an error. See my answer below

Comment: dput(time) gets: list(Location = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L
), .Label = c("Columbus", "Detroit", "Chicago"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(118L, 131L, 174L, 178L, 
    57L, 8L, 91L, 108L, 66L, 91L, 96L, 105L, 129L, 141L, 145L, 
    180L, 190L, 207L, 208L), .Label = c("0:01", "0:05", "0:06" ), class = "factor")

Comment: note: there are lot of columns and rows here I deleted to get to the meat of the problem.

Comment: The `dput` output is sin correct. Can you use `dput(head(time[c("Location","Time")]))` to reduce the size

Comment: dput(head(time[c("Location","Play.Time")]))
structure(list(Location = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Location", 
"Time"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("0:01", 
"0:05", "0:06", "0:19", "0:21", "0:23", "0:30", "0:32", "0:34", ), class = "factor"))

Comment: again, the output is from the larger file.  I used a subset in the information above.  So the output appears incorrect, but it's only because it's from the larger version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking part of what @CAFEBABE recommended and modifying it.

I used

```
mutated_time <- time %>% 
    group_by(Location) %>% 
    summarize(play 
    = sum(as.numeric(Time)/60),
    unitsph = sum(units))
```

and that plus

```
selektor <- as.data.frame(select(distinct(mutated_time), Location,unitsph))
```

got me where I wanted to go. Thank you all for the many helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your time is a a string object. You can use

```
data <- data.frame(loc=c("C","C","D","D"),time=c("1:22","1:23","1:24","1:25"),u=c(1,2,3,4))
basetime <- strptime("00:00","%H:%M")
data$in.hours <- as.double(strptime(data$time,"%H:%M")-basetime)
thing <- data %>% group_by(loc) %>% summarize(sum(u),sum(in.hours))
```

The conversion into hours is not exactly beautiful. It first turns the time into a Posix.ct object to convert it in turn to a double. But guess ok.
The converted data

```
 loc time u in.hours
1   C 1:22 1 1.366667
2   C 1:23 2 1.383333
3   D 1:24 3 1.400000
4   D 1:25 4 1.416667
```

so `1.366` means `1h + 1/3h`.
The final result is then

```
    loc sum(u) sum(in.hours)
  (fctr)  (dbl)         (dbl)
1      C      3      2.750000
2      D      7      2.816667
```

hence for `C` you have 2 hours and `0.75*60 minutes`

Comment: I'm intrigued by this: what does strptime do? also, I printed a subset of variables here.  In sum there are some 8k records.  (goal is to use all of this for a shiny dashboard, reactive items).

Comment: @ike - `?` can find what functions do - `?strptime` for example

Comment: Hi thelatemail: thanks for the suggestion.  I am more curious as to why the answer here used it. For example, I know from the '?strptime' that %H converts the given time to a decimal.  I was interested about why they did this here instead of say, converting to a whole unit otherwise.